# Auth fail on Samba server with LDAP backend‏

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap, share

I'm trying to configure a Samba server to simply use LDAP backend for authenticate users. Just that, I don't care of PDC/BDC, etc.

The samba schema is present in the LDAP, and in the users profile. And this server is already used by an another Samba server which is probably a PDC. But, I don't have write access to the LDAP or the samba server. I can only read de LDAP entries.

I can log via SSH on my samba server using LDAP account, so I think that NSS/PAM stuffs are good.

The thing is that when I try this command:

```
smbclient -d 2  //sandbox-samba.mydomain.com/MyShare  -U user.ldap
```

I get this:

> rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit
>
> (16384) added interface eth0 ip=10.X.X.19 bcast=10.X.X.255
>
> netmask=255.255.255.0 Enter user.ldap's password: session setup
>
> failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

And on the samba server side, I have this in the samba logs:

> [2015/03/24 14:55:19.913036,  2] lib/smbldap.c:1018(smbldap_open_connection)
>
> smbldap_open_connection: connection opened
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:19.916244,  3] lib/smbldap.c:1240(smbldap_connect_system)
>
> ldap_connect_system: successful connection to the LDAP server
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:19.918237,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
>
> check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [MYGROUP][user.ldap]@[CLIENT_WS] with the new password interface
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:19.918387,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
>
> check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [MYDOMAIN][user.ldap]@[CLIENT_WS]
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:19.939873,  2] passdb/pdb_ldap.c:553(init_sam_from_ldap)
>
> init_sam_from_ldap: Entry found for user: user.ldap
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.025999,  2] passdb/pdb_ldap.c:2427(init_group_from_ldap)
>
> init_group_from_ldap: Entry found for group: 1100
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.029060,  2] passdb/pdb_ldap.c:2427(init_group_from_ldap)
>
> init_group_from_ldap: Entry found for group: 1100
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.029424,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:309(ntlm_password_check)
>
> ntlm_password_check: NO NT password stored for user user.ldap.
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.029667,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:442(ntlm_password_check)
>
> ntlm_password_check: Lanman passwords NOT PERMITTED for user user.ldap
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.030792,  2] passdb/pdb_ldap.c:1180(init_ldap_from_sam)
>
> init_ldap_from_sam: Setting entry for user: user.ldap
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.030989,  3] auth/auth_winbind.c:60(check_winbind_security)
>
> check_winbind_security: Not using winbind, requested domain [MYDOMAIN] was for this SAM.
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.031126,  2] auth/auth.c:330(check_ntlm_password)
>
> check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [user.ldap] -> [user.ldap] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.031307,  3] smbd/error.c:81(error_packet_set)
>
> error packet at smbd/sesssetup.c(124) cmd=115 (SMBsesssetupX) NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
>
> [2015/03/24 14:55:20.031968,  3] smbd/server_exit.c:181(exit_server_common)
>
> Server exit (failed to receive smb request)

I don't understand the NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD thing... Where can I look to understand what is going ?

Is it simply possible to just have a samba server which just use LDAP just for authentication ?

I got the same result with a Windows 7 client using GUI interface.

Here is my smb.conf, if it could  help:

> [global]
>
> workgroup = MYDOMAIN
>
> netbios name = machinename
>
> server string = %h
>
> server string = TEST Samba Server Version %v
>
> domain logons = no
>
> domain master = no
>
> log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
>
> max log size = 50
>
> vfs object = full_audit
>
> full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
>
> full_audit:success = all
>
> full_audit:failure = connect
>
> full_audit:facility = local7
>
> full_audit:priority = notice
>
> encrypt passwords = yes
>
> security = user
>
> passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://ldap.mydomain.com
>
> ldap admin dn = "uid=administrator,ou=Users,o=mydomain,c=com"
>
> ldap suffix = o=mydomain, c=com
>
> ldap user suffix = ou=Users
>
> ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
>
> ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
>
> ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap
>
> ldap ssl = no
>
> ldap passwd sync = only
>
> log level = 3
>
> load printers = no
>
> printing = bsd
>
> printcap name = /dev/null
>
> disable spoolss = yes
>
> [MyShare]
>
> comment = MyShare Stuff
>
> path = /srv/share
>
> public = yes
>
> writable = yes
>
> printable = no

Thanks for any help you could give me!

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

You have 'encrypt passwords = yes'. From smb.conf (Samba 3):

> ...
>    In order for encrypted passwords to work correctly smbd(8) must either have access to a local smbpasswd(5) file (see the smbpasswd(8) program for information on how to set up and maintain this file), or set the security = [server|domain|ads] parameter which causes smbd to authenticate against another server.
>    ...

You also have 'security = user' (i.e. none of [server|domain|ads]).